# Find all $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long while now and not getting far.

**Problem:** Let $n \geq 3$. Characterize all vectors $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$M := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle a, x \rangle = 0,\langle b, x \rangle = 0 \ \text{and} \ |\langle c, x \rangle| < 1 \} $$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $k \in \{1,...,n-1\}$

Any help/hints, please?

Comment: This is very confusing. Is this supposed to hold for *every* $k$ or for *some* fixed $k$? I presume that if $n$ is big and $k$ is small, you will answer that there is no solution?

Comment: I am not completely sure. I'm suppose to determine the dimension of $M$ as it depends on $a, b$ and $c$. Is it possible that you write an answer/idea for $n = 3$, then maybe I can take it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\langle a, x\rangle = 0$ and $\langle b, x\rangle = 0$, we see that $x \in \operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp}$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension

$$n - \dim\operatorname{span}\{a, b\} = \begin{cases} n - 2 & a, b\ \text{are linearly independent}\\
n - 1 & a, b\ \text{are linearly dependent but not both zero}\\
n & a = b = 0.
\end{cases}$$

Now note that if $x \in \operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp}$, then $\langle c, x\rangle = \langle c', x\rangle$ where $c'$ is the orthogonal projection of $c'$ onto $\operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp}$. Therefore

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle a, x\rangle = 0, \langle b, x\rangle = 0, |\langle c, x\rangle| < 1\} = \{x \in \operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp} : |\langle c', x\rangle| < 1\}.$$

As $|\langle c', x\rangle| < 1$ is an open condition, we see that $\{x \in \operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp} : |\langle c', x\rangle| < 1\}$ is an open subset of $\operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp}$ and hence a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $\dim\operatorname{span}\{a, b\}^{\perp} \in \{n - 2, n - 1, n\}$ depending on $a$ and $b$ as determined above; note, the dimension does not depend on $c$.